# How can I resolve this syntax error in JPQL?

Tags: jpa, jpql

I am fairly new to `JPQL` and coming from `SQL` there are some things I still need to get familiar with, so the problem might be caused by that fact.
Working with the `CUBA-Framework`, I am trying to create a new entity with a `JPQL` like a form of projection in `SQL` and I already have succeeded in doing so but now with another case, I got a syntax error. So here is my JPQL:

> SELECT NEW
>   com.example.vet.entity.vet_AnimalInformation(a.cage,0,0,'test',0)
>       FROM vet_Animals a

This gets transformed internally into what you can see in the exception below and gives me an error:

```
An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager:
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing 
[SELECT NEWcom.example.vet.entity.vet_AnimalInformation(tempEntityAlias,0,0,'test',0) FROM vet_Cage tempEntityAlias, vet_Animals a where tempEntityAlias.id = a.cage.id].
[71, 72] The SELECT clause has 'NEWcom.example.vet.entity.vet_AnimalInformation' and '(tempEntityAlias, 0, 0, 'test', 0)' that are not separated by a comma.
```

Whyever this restructuring occurs, I can live with that, although in comparison to `SQL` I feel a lack of influence on the statement here :) somehow the constructor is not recognized as such.
What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

edit:
Now I wrote my original SELECT clause in the exact way like it is shown in the error message, after it was automatically rewritten and it works! At least I get another error stating that the constructor with those types of parameters could not be found but at least it is recognized as a constructor.
My guess was then that maybe in rewriting the statement then space between NEW and the contructor gets lost but when I leave that out in my original statement I get a totally different error.

Comment: Your JPQL looks like you are putting a Java constructor into a `SELECT` clause.  What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Since JPQL only returns entities I have to wrap the desired fields into a new object. With the NEW keyword you can create a new entity inside the SELECT with those fields and return the entity.

For example in SQL I was used to write:
SELECT animals.cage_id, SUM(animals.count) FROM animals GROUP BY animals.cage_id

This is not possible in JPQL.

Comment: Yes, it is possible in JPQL as far as I know.